# Icon google sign in button didnt appear

Tags: android

[enter image sdescription here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFIZj.png)

I tried to using google sign-in button template on android. But the icon didnt appear. Here's the code

```
 <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="142dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="453dp" />
```